# Avraham Avinu had a seudas Purim?

Tags: purim

I am trying to locate the cited sources that are mentioned. (Divrei Yechezkel Purim, Sifsei Chachamim, and the Yalkut Moshe).

Also interested in any other associated information relating to this.

This is taken from Sefer Pirsumei Nissa (Tzvi Hirsch Weiss) page תקנב.

[image]

Comment: See also [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/167923/p/7/t/0.70232800342471311234/fs/N0tL1O8JcMrFxYCN8ScH9Lm0uHHEF7EXlmtZaKYUnuw9/start/0/end/10/c)

Comment: @Shmuel Thank You, can you please put that in answer format, thank you for sharing this additional resource.

Answer (score 3):

The [sefer Ne"imat HaMegillah](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/167923/p/7/t/2328003424713112341234/fs/N0tL1O8JcMrFxYCN8ScH9Lm0uHHEF7EXlmtZaKYUnuw9/start/0/end/10/c) by Rabbi Eliezer Friedman (p. 5) writes as follows:

> ובאמת כבר מצינו שגם אברהם אבינו עשה סעודת פורים וכמו שמובא בספר דברי יחזקאל שכתב שם בשם מוהר"ר ברוך ממעזביז זי"ע עה"פ ויעש אברהם משתה גדול ביום הגמל את יצחק בנו תיבת הגמל אותיות מגלה שעשה"א משתה בפורימיב ע"כ - We have already noted that Avraham Avinu had a seudas purim, as stated in Divrei Yechezkel, who wrote in the name of Boruch of Medzhybizh. Avraham made a great feast on the day that he gave Yitzchak [....]

Refer to footnote 11 in the sefer, which gives sort of a proof for the statement in general and explains it:

> ועיין בספר ילקוט משה בשער הפרפראות שכתב דהרי יצחק נולד בפסח ונוהגין שלא להניק הילד כי אם כ"ג חדשים נמצא דיום הגמלו היה בפורים וכתיב ויעש משתה גדול מכאן ראיה שצריך לשתות בפורים

So, according to this, it is said in at least two seforim, the Divrei Yechezkel, and in the words of R' Boruch of Medzhybizh.

*(I have trouble translating the last few words, please feel free to do that :)).*

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a friend, i was able to locate where this is mentioned in the Divrei Yechzkiel.

I was also able to locate the Yalkut Moshe [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=3996&st=&pgnum=94&hilite=) connecting the day that Yitzchok was weaned off breast milk was purim.

[image]